# How to disallow scripting tags in text boxes

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am trying to implement `post` functionality in my website and I am working on `codeigniter(PHP)`. My problem is when I enter and submit:

```
<script>
alert("aaaa");
</script>
```

The JavaScript starts working and the code is executed when the page loads, so how to sanitize scripting tags in user input?

I want all kind of coding tags to be displayed as simple text in my text box when submitted

Comment: You need to sanitize your users input ALWAYS. You can never trust your users, nor you can trust any input external to your application. For example if your are reading from a DB that is used by another applications IMO you shoud sanitize the data that you get from there, because you can never be sure that the data there is safe.

Comment: use ..." xss_clean() " ...in your rule or validation so it will change and your problem is solved

Answer (score 2):

Disregard this answer, I'm leaving it here only for people who are misled by the original question about "script" tags, not "all HTML" tags.

---

If you would like to let your users enter arbitraty HTML code, but prevent XSS vulnerabilities, this is what HTML Purifier was built for.

http://htmlpurifier.org/

This *does* also protect against iframe, embed, and the like. It is whitelist based and well tested.

Comment: The user wants `all kind of coding tags to be displayed as simple text in my text box when submitted`.

Comment: That's nice, too bad the edit was made so late in the game, I can't retract my downvotes.

Comment: No worries, some people aren't capable of interpreting requirements of users that are new to things.

Comment: He has asked how to remove all "coding" tags, not all "markup" tags. HTML Purifier is still a better fit because it is configurable in how it handles CSS content.

Answer (score 1):

For More Information About htmlspecialchars http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: SCRIPTING tags are HTML tags :) and this should be usgested to avoid `<embed></embed>`, `<iframe></iframe>` and etc.

Comment: Exactly. `<script>` is one of the worst, but by no means the only problematic tag in cases like this.

Comment: Sorry For this but i think this might help http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Since it's user input, there's a good chance he wants a way to let users format their input. My answer still addresses the concerns outlined here while allowing users to format how they like. HTML Purifier uses a whitelist system and is designed for this **EXACT** task.

Comment: Yes, but why bother with a library when there are built in functions that perform the **EXACT** task he wants?

Comment: He has asked how to remove all "coding" tags, not all "markup" tags. HTML Purifier is still a better fit because it is configurable in how it handles CSS content.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of **`htmlentities()`** if you are going to output the content on your browser.

```
echo htmlentities("<script>alert('aaaa');</script>");
```

Comment: The question is "how to avoid scripting tags in textboxes" not how to avoid HTML tags.